# Replace space with underscore in Swift 4 Text Fields

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a Text Field in my **User Registration** screen called; *Username*.

To avoid users leaving this field empty - and to make it easy for them to use a username that simply combines their First and Last names - I currently have an **IBAction** that triggers when "**Editing did End**" to take the value from the Full Name in lowercase.

```
@IBAction func fullNameEditingEnded(_ sender: Any) {
    let userName = fullnameTextfield.text?.lowercased()
    usernameTextfield.text = userName
    }
```

I would like to replace the space with an underscore. What is the best approach to do this? Is it a for in loop or is there something simpler?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this Also it's better to trim end spaces as not to be replace-able with _

```
let aString = "first last"
let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
```

---

```
@IBAction func fullNameEditingEnded(_ sender: Any) {
    let userName = fullnameTextfield.text?.lowercased()
    usernameTextfield.text = userName.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
}
```